# SyntaxError: unexpected indent

Tags: python-3.x

```
if price<500:
    print('I will buy the samsung phone.')
    else:print('i will be happy with lg')
```

como pongo el valor de price para que me proporcione con el resultado final?

El error que tengo es SyntaxError: unexpected indent cuando agrego el valor price=450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python funciona con tabulaciones, por lo que deberías tabular el interior del else e introducirle un salto de línea:

```
if price<500:
    print('I will buy the samsung phone.')
else:
    print('i will be happy with lg')
```

Comment: Resuelto, muchas Gracias Grommy.